# How to debug android UI styles

Tags: user-interface, android-view, android, android-debug

Please do you know about any tool which would allow me to debug Android UI in the way web debug tools work? I mean view which style is applied to each particular View, or also I would like to be able to see some inheritance tree etc..Do you guys know about something like that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to look which style is applied is to look in xml. Simply search for Style and you'll be able to go through them one at a time, but something like web debug doesn't exist as far as I know.

Inheritance trees for styles are also not present and you'll have to go through them the hard way (writting on paper or something). In general android styles is a pain to learn but when you've learned to navigate it you'll be able to live with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a method to do so other than Warpzit's method. In Eclipse, there is a helpful tool to see your UI hierarchy though. When in debug mode, open the "Devices" window (if you can't find it: Alt+Shift+Q, Q). Then click the "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator".

You can see some view attributes there as well as the way it's build up.

There's also a hierarchy viewer in the SDK tools/ directory, but I haven't used it yet.

[image: devices view]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but this is what I do because I don't know of a better way.

On Eclipse, I start with the xml layout in question and I drill down by pressing the Ctrl key (or the Command key on a Mac) and clicking on the style in question (the style name becomes an hyperlink when that key is pressed down and I hover the mouse over it). Then, I use the yellow arrow keys on the Eclipse toolbar to come back through each pane of code once I need to go back to the root of where I started from.

On Android Studio Preview, which unfortunately I can't use at work because everyone uses Eclipse, the same shortcuts work as well, but unlike Eclipse, the navigation support and the refactoring support work much better, I'd recommend that you look at Android Studio if you're not satisfied with Eclipse's support (my only warning is that once you have a version of Android Studio that works for you, that you do not update it, because updates of Android Studio tend to break it frequently).

Answer (score -1):

To find it, please go to Layout Inspector,

**Tools --> Android --> Layout Inspector**